# cfspreadsheet escape comma in comma separated row insert

Tags: list, coldfusion, spreadsheet, cfspreadsheet

The function for adding a row to a coldfusion spreadsheet is `SpreadsheetAddrow` which accepts data as "A comma delimited list of cell entries, one per column."

Some of my data has commas within it. How do I escape the commas within my data without escaping the commas in the list?

I am currently creating an array with the contents of the row, then converting it to a list to add to the spreadsheet:

```
    <cfset row = ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfloop list="#structKeyList(setRecord.columns)#" index="key">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(row, "#Evaluate(key)#")>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset spreadsheetAddRow(xlsObj, "#ArrayToList(row)#")>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you want to add to the sheet is in a query object (recordset) then the simplest solution is to use SpreadSheetAddRows(), (as opposed to SpreadSheetAddRow - singular).

```
<cfset SpreadSheetAddRows( xlsObj,query )>
```

The sheet columns are mapped from the query columns, so commas in the data won't matter.

Even if the data is in another format or you are only adding a single row, converting it to a query object is an effective way of getting round the issue, see http://cfsimplicity.com/30/workaround-for-spreadsheetaddrow-limitation-when-column-values-contain-commas

Comment: @inKit - What type of object are you using? If it is a `query`, this approach is much better. If it is a `struct`, then converting to query is an additional step. So SpreadsheetSetCellValue is probably more efficient.

Comment: It is a query, I am using the structure to map query column names against headings for the spreadsheet.

Comment: @inKit - Ah, okay. I thought it was a `struct`. For queries, `SpreadSheetAddRows` is much more efficient.

Comment: What if you would like to specify the columns in a query. I tried the work around, but adding single quotes around #myCommaRow" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the [ability to specify a different delimiter](http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=86522) is not supported yet. Since you are already looping, you may as well skip the array and use [SpreadsheetSetCellValue](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6731.html) instead. You should be able to eliminate the evaluate() as well.

```
<cfset cols = structKeyArray(yourStruct) >
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cols)#" index="c">
   <cfset SpreadsheetSetCellValue(xlsObj, yourStruct[ cols[c] ], lastRow, c)>
</cfloop>
<cfset lastRow++>
...
```

**Update:** However, if the base object is a query, not a structure, then it is more efficient to use CfSimplicity's suggestion of `SpreadSheetAddRows`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the commas with the character "#130;" (see the source: https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/ascii-codes/), which looks the same as comma but doesn't create any problems.